# iPhone screen turning black after launch image

Tags: ios, error-handling, xcode4.5

So everything were going great and my app was almost done, until this happened. Did not make any changes exept trying to run it in iOS Simulater. When I was going to try it on my iPhone again the screen turns black after the launch image!! And I don't get any errors in xcode.

I've tried to clean my project, resetting iOS Simulator (just for kicks), restarting my Macbook, restarting iPhone, delete the app from homescreen and install it again.

Building for iOS 6 on my iPhone 5.

AppDelegate.h

```
//
//  AppDelegate.h
//  
//
//  Created by Øyvind Larsen Runestad on 13.01.13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Øyvind Larsen Runestad. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate> {

IBOutlet UITabBarController *tabBarController;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@property(nonatomic, readonly) UITabBarController *moreNavigationController;

@end
```

AppDelegate.m

```
//
//  AppDelegate.m
//  
//
//  Created by Øyvind Larsen Runestad on 13.01.13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Øyvind Larsen Runestad. All rights reserved.
//

#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later. 
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}

@end
```

Anyone have any solutions to this problem?

Best regards, 
Øyvind Larsen Runestad.

**EDIT: SOLVED!**

> > Okay, i sorted it out. The Main Storyboard in the project was set to blank. All I had to do was to change this to MainStoryboard.
> >
> > Seems like my AppDelegate is okay after all @H2CO3 ;)

Comment: It's really hard to help you with this without seeing some code / specs! What iOS are you building for, and can you show us your app delegate methods

Comment: Check your interface builder connections

Comment: Updated post. What connections do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

If this **really** is your actual code, then the problem is the following: you don't create the key window when the app launches.

Comment: But I haven't made any changes? I just copy/pasted my AppDelegate files. The app has been running fine until this point on my iPhone 5.

Comment: @ØyvindL.Runestad Your `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method is empty and you don't set up a key window. This code cannot possibly work.

Comment: This is my AppDelegate files and I haven't been doing a thing to them. Do you have any ideas what I can put there to possibly make it work?

Comment: @ØyvindL.Runestad `self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds] autorelease]; [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];`

Comment: AppDelegate.m:15:81: Expected identifier

Comment: - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds]]; [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}

Comment: The autorelease was not supported bu ARC.

Comment: @ØyvindL.Runestad Then omit it.

Comment: Omit it? What do you mean?

Comment: @ØyvindL.Runestad If you don't include the call to autorelease it will vanish.

Comment: @ØyvindL.Runestad Euh, exclude the call to autorelease?

Comment: AppDelegate.m:15:81: Expected identifier – Øyvind L. Runestad 12 mins ago 

I did remove it and I get this error.

Comment: @ØyvindL.Runestad Check the number of brackets. One method call, one pair of brackets. And learn the Objective-C language before asking questions like this. This is exhausting.

Comment: I'm sorry for bothering you. But I needed help when something this unexpected happens.